# Spring security: Authentication manager and global security config with Java config from xml config

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using spring security **4.2.5.RELEASE** and spring **4.3.16.RELEASE**
My XML configuration working fine and its like below

```
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" access-decision-manager-ref="methodAccessDecisionManager">
        <security:expression-handler ref="methodExpressionHandler"/>
    </security:global-method-security>
    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
                <security:salt-source user-property="saltSource" />
            </security:password-encoder>
        </security:authentication-provider>         

        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <security:password-encoder ref="bcryptPasswordEncoder"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

I have also http security configuration. need this configuration with java configuration. but can not do it because I am not finding any solution for
**`access-decision-manager-ref="methodAccessDecisionManager"`**  and **`<security:expression-handler ref="methodExpressionHandler"/>`**

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .addFilterAt(switchUserProcessingFilter(), SwitchUserFilter.class)
        .authorizeRequests()
        .accessDecisionManager(webAccessDecisionManager())
        .antMatchers("/pages/login.jsf").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/pages/expired.jsf").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/css/*").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/images/*").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/pages/testui/*").access("hasRole('PRIVILEGE_TESTER')")
        .antMatchers("/pages/client/*").access("hasAnyRole('PRIVILEGE_USE_TENDERING, PRIVILEGE_MANAGE_USERS')")
        .antMatchers("/pages/html5/**").access("hasAnyRole('PRIVILEGE_USE_TENDERING, PRIVILEGE_USE_SPOTREQUEST')")
        .antMatchers("/moker/*").access("isAuthenticated()")
        .antMatchers("/e/*").access("hasRole('PRIVILEGE_FILE')")
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/pageogin.jsf")
        .usernameParameter("j_username")
        .passwordParameter("j_password")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/j_sy_check")
        .failureUrl("/pages/l_error=1")
        .successHandler(tenderEasyAuthSuccessHandler())
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout")
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/pages/logout.jsf")
        .and();
    }

     @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       auth
       .userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
       .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder().isPasswordValid(encPass, rawPass, salt))

    }

}
```

But here I am finding anything for:

`access-decision-manager-ref="methodAccessDecisionManager", security:expression-handler ref=methodExpressionHandler` and 
`security:salt-source user-property=saltSource`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify a method expression handler and access decision manager, use a configuration based on `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class MyGlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private MethodSecurityExpressionHandler methodExpressionHandler;

    @Autowired
    private AccessDecisionManager methodAccessDecisionManager;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return methodExpressionHandler;
    }

    @Override
    protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
        return methodAccessDecisionManager;
    }

}
```

(Remove `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` from your `SecurityConfig`).

See also [Spring Security Reference Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#globalmethodsecurityconfiguration).